# How to optimize cost of concatenation of n strings

Tags: algorithm, optimization, complexity-theory, string-concatenation

If we are given n strings and their lengths and an add(string s1,string s2) function which would concatenate the string s2 with s1 and return s3. How would we optimize the cost of concatenation of all these strings into one big string.

If such a function was not given we could simply create the output string of size (n1 + n2 + ...nn) and keep appending to it characters of each string. But, with this function given we'd have to traverse input string s1 to find it's end and then start concatenating string s2 to it.

so if lengths of strings are 2, 6, 1, 3, 4 ..

```
add (s1, s2) traversal for length 2, op string of length 8
add (s1, s3) traversal for length (2+6) op string of length 9
add (s1, s4) traversal for length (2+6+1) op string of length 12
add (s1, s5) traversal for length (2+6+1+3) op string of length 16...and so on..
```

Comment: Can you provide a more precise definition of what you consider the "cost" of an `add()` operation to be?

Comment: I gave an example that here by cost I mean number of times I have to traverse entire string and the traversal size grows in terms of size of input strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"with this function given we'd have to traverse input string s1 
to find it's end and then start concatenating string s2 to it. "
```

You can concat the string character by character right when you traverse it. After you append a small string to the result string, you can get hold of the pointer which is pointing to the end of the result string. So while adding next small string, use that so that you wont have to traverse all way till that position again.

Answer (score 0):

Thera are two ways to doing it .

1. Sort the array and then keep concatenating , it will minimise the cost .

   Time Complexity O(nlogn) where n is size of array.  (Say you have used quick sort)
   Space Complexity O(logn)
2. Create Min Heap of array.Now remove 1st two min from heap , add them
   and add to heap again , how much does it take ?

   Creating Min-Heap will take O(n).
   Removing 1st and 2nd Min will take O(n)+O(n), wait how ? , replace root with last element 
   and call heapify , it takes O(logn) so does removing . Now we have to do the same thing for
   remaining n-2 elements so it will take total O(n-2(logn)) thats worst , 
   add two elements take O(1) and inserting back and adjusting heap again will take O(logn)
   Overall it will be order of O(nlogn) and we can also see more call and instruction needed 
   in such case.

Overall problem just requires sorting the array and we can minimise the cost to concatenation but if we need to think more about choosing right sorting algorithm if we are considering time ann space

Comment: Actually the question posed by OP is not clear, and thus it's unclear what this answer is trying to achieve.

Comment: @justhalf , question asked to minimize the cost of concatenating two strings , lets take an example 1,5,2 are the lengths of given string in array(unsorted , appends in order)
1+5=6
6+2=8
total cost=14 can you Optimize this total cost?   Yes what if sort this array , it will be 1 2 5 and then append 1+2=3  and then 3+5=8 so total cost will 11 which is < 14 so sorting is one of the way to achieve optimisation .